# Images in array, HOW TO?

Tags: ios, xcode, arrays, imageview, mutable

I made 26 buttons, A-Z and when I click them the image of the button I pressed will display in an image view, when I click A, it displays A, When I click B it will display B etc.

The problem I have is that they won't display next to each other, I have 6 image views and I want the first letter to fill first box second letter second box etc.

I just don't know how to do this, I've been trying a lot of ways now and i'm pretty sure i'll need to use arrays just can't get the code right.

This is a picture of where I am now I'm already past number 1 so it's like number 2 except for showing next each other ofc.

hope someone can tell me here is the picture:

http://img213.imageshack.us/img213/4500/questionow.png

thanks

This is what I got now    .h

```
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview1;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview2;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview3;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview4;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview5;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview6;
}

-(IBAction)showA;
-(IBAction)showB;
-(IBAction)showC;
-(IBAction)showD;
-(IBAction)showE;
-(IBAction)showF;
-(IBAction)showG;
-(IBAction)showH;
-(IBAction)showI;
-(IBAction)showJ;
-(IBAction)showK;
-(IBAction)showL;
-(IBAction)showM;
-(IBAction)showN;
-(IBAction)showO;
-(IBAction)showP;
-(IBAction)showQ;
-(IBAction)showR;
-(IBAction)showS;
-(IBAction)showT;
-(IBAction)showU;
-(IBAction)showV;
-(IBAction)showW;
-(IBAction)showX;
-(IBAction)showY;
-(IBAction)showZ;
```

.m

```
-(IBAction)showA {

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"A.png"];

[imageview1 setImage:img];

}

-(IBAction)showB {

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"B.png"];

[imageview1 setImage:img];  

}
```

Etc.

Hope someone can tell me how to make this or has some sample code for me because I don't quite  get the arrays even after seeing a lot of tutorials on them.

thanks Don

Comment: Have you tried simply setting their positions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always do:

```
- (void)setNextImage:(UIImage *)image {
    if (imageview1.image == nil) {
        [imageView1 setImage:image]
    } else if (imageView2.image == nil){
        [imageView2 setImage:image]
    } // ... Through all 6 images
}
```

and then in each of your button actions just call:

```
[self setNextImage:img];
```

instead of setting it directly.

Comment: Would make even more sense to put the imageView pointers into an array and index the array to pick which one.

Comment: Oke thanks both of you, got a question when I would do it this way is it any bad? because then I will use your way hot licks but If it works and it's alright then It's fine for me. but I don't really know what you mean but I'll look it up then. Heard from 2-3 guys that It was possible with an array so've been struggling with that all day although inafzigers way was what I was thinking myself at first let me give it a try! thanks

Comment: With only 6 items I think that this is fine.  Much more than that and I would definitely say to use an array.  In this case though I think that either way is a valid approach.

Comment: Hey guys thanks so much it's working! really nice so good to see something finally work couldn't have done it without you! :D:D only 1 thing, when I run it from Xcode it would breakdown when I clicked the second image, breakpoint 1.1 or something it would say in xCode only when I press stop in Xcode, then return to the simulator and run the app again then it works perfectly fine. how come?

Comment: Oke thanks ya the words in my game can only be 6 characters long maybe expand it to 7 in the future but I'm guessing that isn't such a problem thanks man for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Using an array is not hard.  Just declare either a standard C array of UIImageView* or an NSArray, inited like:  `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:imageView1, imageView2 ... imageView6, nil]`.

Then have a position counter `pos` declared at the instance level, and you simply do:

```
[imageViewArray objectAtIndex:pos].image = imageParm; pos++;
```

(Or, for the C array, `imageViewArray[pos].image = imageParm; pos++;`.)

Comment: I'll try this out tomorrow just so I know how it works thank you do you know why It breakdown now when I hit the second letter but when I stop Xcode and go back to the simulator, run the app again it's working fine? when Xcode opens it makes the } else if (imageView2.image == nil){
        [imageView2 setImage:image] green line and then says breakdown

Comment: What do you mean "breakdown"?  If you mean "breakpoint" then likely you've set one at that location -- there'd be a sort of arrow marker in the left margin.

Comment: how come? I mean it runs when I stop Xcode but I don't think it's alright hehe

Comment: Guess not hèhè pretty New to this

Comment: Nevermind I found it thanks for all your help Guys ill try your arrays out when I get back from work thanks Guys!